# Tiling with triangles of same circumradius and inradius

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

Consider a pair of positive real numbers $r$ and $R$ with $r<R/2$. Then we can form infinitely many triangles all with circumradius $R$ and inradius $r$.

For any such pair, the resulting triangles all have different areas and perimeters. (As we go over triangles in each set, the areas and perimeters increase and decrease together; however, the diameter is maximized by a triangle which does not maximize area or perimeter.)

**Question:** For a specified inradius-circumradius pair, can we choose from among the resulting triangles a pair-wise non-congruent set that can tile the plane?

Note 1: If an infinite set of triangles all have equal area and perimeter, we cannot choose a mutually non-congruent set from among them that can tile the plane: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04504

Note 2: Is it possible to tile the plane with pair-wise non-congruent triangles all of the same inradius? Or for all triangles of the same circumradius?. I guess yes to both because both are very loosely constrained problems. I also don't know of properties that are invariant across all triangles with both radii equal.

Comment: Two of the resulting triangles are isosceles, you can use them to tile the plane

Comment: The triangles used should be pairwise non-congruent. We are not allowed to repeat any given tile. Thanks.

Comment: Does not the same argument as in the cited paper work here?

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure. The desired tiling is 'locally finite' as defined in the linked paper. But for ex, Theorem 5 there says: "Let T be a locally finite tiling of the plane with triangles, and suppose that the lengths of their sides belong to interval [1, 2). Then there are two triangles in T that share a side." But we can't say that the triangles in our qn have side lengths that lie in that range, esp if r2 is small. Moreover, in our question, even if two triangles share an edge, that is not obviously a problem since areas and perimeters of the triangles are all different.