# Tiling with a one-parameter family of non-congruent triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling, triangles

This post continues [Tiling with triangles of same circumradius and inradius](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423942/tiling-with-triangles-of-same-circumradius-and-inradius).

The following are known about infinite sets of triangles that can be parametrized with one variable:

- from an infinite set of triangles all of equal area and perimeter, we cannot choose a mutually non-congruent set that can tile the plane: (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04504).
- if one partitions the plane into equilateral triangles of different sizes, then arbitrarily small triangles necessarily occur (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08903.pdf).

**Question:** Can one construct a one-parameter family of triangles from which a mutually non-congruent set of non-degenerate triangles with dimensions bounded both above and below can be chosen to tile the plane?

Comment: Are you satisfied with triangles with altitude $1$ and lateral sides $2+x$ and $2+2x$, for all $x>0$?

Comment: Thanks. I guess you mean to (1) cut the plane into strips of width 1, (2) tile each strip with identical isosceles triangles and (3) displace each vertex in the layout towards +ve x direction by a unique distance. We map +ve integers one-tone with the vertices and triangles in the layout and x-displace each numbered vertex by a small constant d, d/2, d/3, and so on. Then,, we have (a) all triangles non-congruent (b) their dimensions bounded and (c) change in position of each vertex = d/x with  x real and ranging from 1 to infinity and we selecting only integral values of x. Hope I got you.