# Tiling with triangles with same Steiner ellipses

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling, conic-sections

We continue from [Tiling with triangles of same circumradius and inradius](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423942/tiling-with-triangles-of-same-circumradius-and-inradius) .

**Definitions:** Given any triangle, its Steiner circumellipse is the unique circumellipse (ellipse that touches the triangle at its vertices) whose center is the triangle's centroid. The Steiner inellipse is the unique ellipse inscribed in the triangle and tangent to the sides of the triangle at their midpoints.

Given an ellipse E:

1. can we choose from those triangles for which E is the Steiner circumellipse, a pair-wise non-congruent set of triangles that tile the plane?
2. Can we choose from those triangles for which E is the Steiner inellipse, a pairwise non-congruent set of triangles that tile the plane?

**Further query:** As was observed in above linked page, given two positive real numbers r1 and r2 with r2 < r1/2, one can form infinitely many triangles all with circumradius r1 and inradius r2. Son one asks: Under what condition(s) will two specified ellipses be the Steiner circumellipse and inellipse of infinitely many triangles (or a unique triangle)? Basically, how do we characterize those triangles for which two specified ellipses are the Steiner ellipses?